# Error enabling flyspell in emacs - aspell MacOS

Tags: init-file, osx, flyspell

I am having some difficulty getting flyspell/aspell to run on emacs 27.2, MacOS 12.01. I think I need to install or enable a dictionary, but no ideas on how to do this.

If I type 'M-x flyspell-mode' I get the following error:

```
Starting new Ispell process /usr/local/bin/aspell with default dictionary...done
Error enabling Flyspell mode:
(Error: No word lists can be found for the language "en_GB".)
```

Sounds like a dictionary is missing. I have the following in my `init.el`

```
    ;; Spell-check
(require 'flyspell)
(setq flyspell-issue-message-flag nil
      ispell-local-dictionary "en_GB"
      ispell-program-name "/usr/local/bin/aspell")

(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'flyspell-prog-mode)
```

If I type `which aspell` in Terminal it returns `/usr/local/bin/aspell`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need make sure aspell command line program is installed. If it's not installed, run `brew install aspell`, see https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/aspell.rb

To specify the dictionary which aspell uses,

```
(setq ispell-extra-args '("--lang=en_US"))
```

I answered lots of questions about flyspell, see [https://emacs.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:202+[flyspell]](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:202+%5Bflyspell%5D)

You can also read my article, http://blog.binchen.org/posts/what-s-the-best-spell-check-set-up-in-emacs/

Or uses my package `wucuo` (https://github.com/redguardtoo/wucuo) to replace `flyspell-mode` and `flyspell-prog-mode`.

Most people are confused on spell checking in Emacs, so let me clarify a few things,

- In good old days, people use `ispell.el`. These days, people use `flyspell.el`. `flyspell` does use a few APIs from `ispell`, but they are basically two independent packages. Setting up other ispell variables (except `ispell-extra-args` and `ispell-program-name`) might have no effect on flyspell at all.
- `flyspell` needs cli program to do the actual spell checking thing. The cli program could be `aspell` or `hunspell`.
- Setting up the options passed to aspell (the cli program) is straight forward. One variable `ispell-extra-args` is enough.
- Setting up the options passed to hunspell (the cli program) is more complicated. You can see my other answers for details.

Comment: Thank you Chen, very helpful. I would only add that after `brew install Aspell` I had to change the location of Aspell to `ispell-program-name "/opt/homebrew/bin/aspell"`. Trivial, but I thought I better record that for posterity.